# Angular 8: Disable use of an imported component

Tags: angular, jasmine

One of the angular components being used is imported from a library. However, the library also contains a second component which is similar to the first component. Using it causes some inconsistencies. So I'm trying to eliminate using it.

Presently, it is not possible to change the library because the first component is used in several places. Is there a way to disable the second component?

```
<first-component></first-component> <!--Should work-->

<second-component></second-component> <!--Should not work-->
```

I tried writing a jasmine test at the root component that ensures that the component is never used. However, it could fail because the second component could be conditionally rendered within an ngIf. It's also okay if I can somehow poison the second component so that the build fails whenever I compile. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the component.

```
fixture = TestBed.overrideComponent(SecondComponent, { set: { template: '<span>Hello</span> }}).createComponent(SecondComponent);
```

Check [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/testing/components/injecting-dependencies/overriding) link out.